# Using function to update case class value in scala Quill

Tags: scala, quill.io

I have following case class

```scala
case class Tag(key: String, value: String, modifiedDate: Date)
```

And I have a data access object that looks like this:

```scala
class TagDao(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext, val ctx: PostgresAsyncContext[SnakeCase]) {
  def update(tag: Tag): Future[Int] = 
    performIO(
      runIO(
        quote {
          query[Tag]
            .filter(_.id == tag.id)
            .update(lift(tag))
            .returning(_.id)
        }
      )
    )
}
```

> I want `modifiedDate` field of `Tag` in update method to be replaced by `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. How can it be done?

One alternative is before updating I set the `modifiedDate` manually in the code

Comment: I ended up using database trigger for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `copy` method from case class object and pass new Date contained current date:

```
def update(tag: Tag): Future[Int] = 
    performIO(
      runIO(
        quote {
          query[Tag]
            .filter(_.id == tag.id)
            .update(
              lift(tag.copy(modifiedDate = new Date()))
            )
            .returning(_.id)
        }
      )
    )
```